# Mysql getting all joined records both tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join, medoo

I'm using a great php framework for working with my database, medoo.php.  Link to medoo docs for reference: http://medoo.in/doc

What I Want To Happen:

- Return all records from joined tables, where it matches one or more conditions from a right table. (main table is 'items')
- Includes matching/joined records from the right table.  (all 'tags' related to 'items' returned in this case).

What Is Currently Happening:

- Returns records from left table (items) joined with right table (tags).  However, it's only returning the records explicitly containing tags from the WHERE condition.  I want all tags joined to the items, on items that have tags matching the WHERE condition.

Let's get some code to better illustrate the issue:

```
//example 'items' table
    id    -   123
    name  -   'test'
    desc  -   'testing'

//example 'tags' table
    id    -   100
    name  -   'tag1'

//example 'taglist' table (relational)
    id      -   10
    itemid  -   123
    tagid   -   100
```

That illustrates the basic setup, minimized a bit for clarity.

Then, using medoo, I'm selecting from 'items' and joining tags/taglist with left joins (currently).  The WHERE clause: tag.id matches the posted tagid to search.    Also tried taglist.tagid in the WHERE.

The results returned are of all 'items' that contain tags matching the WHERE clause, as you'd expect.  However, I want all of the tags that go with those items, not just the tags I searched (which is what I get).

I'm thinking it must be something to do with the JOINs or the WHERE clause, but I must say I'm lost after hours of attempts, research and more attempts.  Hoping someone can give me a quick hand, spotting where I've likely made an error in my logic.

For further reference, here is what the full query setup, using medoo.

```
//setup query
$table = 'items';
$join = [
    "[>]taglist(tl)" => ["id" => "itemid"],
    "[>]filelist(fl)" => ["id" => "itemid"],
    "[>]tags(t)" => ["tl.tagid" => "id"],
    "[>]files(f)" => ["fl.fileid" => "id"]
];
$cols = [
    "items.id(id)",
    "items.itemid(itemid)",
    "items.name(name)",
    "items.def(def)",
    "items.class(class)",
    "items.timeline(timeline)",
    "t.id(tagid)",
    "t.name(tagname)",
    "f.id(fileid)",
    "f.name(filename)",
    "f.path(filepath)",
    "f.type(filetype)",
    "tl.tagid"
];
$where = [
    "AND" => ["tl.tagid" => $tags],
    "ORDER" => ["items.id DESC","t.name ASC"],
    "LIMIT" => [$start,$limit]
];

// Do query
$results = $db->select($table, $join, $cols, $where);
```

If you're not familiar with medoo, this should still illustrate how the query is setup fairly simply.  (Query works just fine, I'm just not getting all the results I want).

Thank you for any advice.  I'm learning a heck of a lot this week!

Answer (score 0):

If you do `leftside LEFT JOIN rightside ON something` and then do `WHERE rightside.column = something` you convert the LEFT JOIN into a straight JOIN.

Straight JOINs suppress rows from the `leftside` that don't match the `ON` in the join.

So try getting rid of your WHERE condition.

**Edit** I don't know the framework you mention.

But, to get every item that has a particular tagid, you do this.

```
      SELECT DISTINCT itemid FROM taglist WHERE tagid = $tags
```

Then you can do your main query with

```
    WHERE items.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT itemid FROM taglist WHERE tagid = $tags)
```

to filter out just the items with matching tags. Your main query will fetch all the tags, including the one with `tagid = $tags` and all the others, but only for the items having the matching tag.  It's all set theory at its heart.

Comment: Hi Ollie, thank you for that info.  It seems inline with what is happening.  I have other scripts with different where conditions and similar setups, and I get the desired results. In this case, I need to find a workaround because this script is specifically for searching tags.  -- I don't like the idea, but perhaps 2 separate queries, the first creating an array of item ids and the second selecting those ids.  (That explains why none of my attempts made a difference!  Oh well, live and learn :P)